# removing ids with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following issue:

I am parsing a large xml document and then I am automatically generating id numbers for my `<h1>` and `<p>` the header starts with 10 and the paragraph starts with 3000

what I want to know is if there is a way to count  for instance the amount of headers and hide them except for the first 12.

I don't want to enter for instance

```
$('#11').hide();
```

for each and every id.

Here is what I have written which works and creates the header id, to which I then need to give the first 12 a different style. The issue is removing or hiding the other "items" after the twelfth.

```
$(xml).find('Item').each(function () {

            if ($(this).attr('headline') > '') {
                var headline = $('<h1></h1>').appendTo(default_slide);
                headline.attr('id', headline_counter);
                headline.addClass('sa-l');
                headline_counter++;

                headline.append($(this).attr('headline'));


                if ($('<h1 id="10">')) {
                    $('#10').attr('style', 'top:10px;left:80px;font-weight: 500; text-align: center;width:340px;font-size:60px;color:#1d1d1d;text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;white-space: nowrap;');
                }
```

Comment: `$(selector).eq(11).hide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("p:gt(11)").hide();` is the right solution.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `id`s for this at all, you can use the [`:gt` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) or the [`slice` method](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) if you prefer to avoid pseudo-selectors.

[Live Example of Both](http://jsbin.com/verusefa/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/verusefa/1/edit))

Using `:gt`:

```
$("p:gt(11)").hide();
```

`:gt` means "greater than" and works with zero-based indexes. So the above would hide the thirteenth (index 12) onward, skipping the first twelve. (And obviously something similar for the `h1`s.)

This obviously would work best if you added a class to the relevant paragraphs, so you could target them more effectively:

```
$("p.some-class:gt(11)").hide();
```

Using `slice`, which accepts start and (optionally) end indexes to select from the jQuery set:

```
$("p").slice(12).hide();
// Or of course
$("p.some-class").slice(12).hide();
```

Those slice starting with the thirteenth element (index 11).

---

Side note: If you use `id` values that start with digits, the CSS selectors for them are awkward to write. `#11` is an invalid CSS selector, for instance. It's *possible*, but you have to use escapes that are *really* hard to read. More in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), but the correct selector for `id="11"` is `#\31\31`, and of course if you're going to put that in a JavaScript string, you have to escape the backslashes, so it becomes `"#\\31\\31"`. Pretty non-obvious, especially if you're dealing with `id="3172"` which (as a JavaScript string) is `"#\\33\\31\\37\\32"`. [Example](http://jsbin.com/mekurawa/1)

Comment: I think the OP wants to hide all except the first 12, so it should be `gt` not `lt`.

Comment: And now I've fixed the OBOE! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use gt selector to target element with index greater than:

```
$("h1:gt(11)").hide();
```

> *note: :gt selector has index starting from 0*

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( "h1" ).each(function(index) {
   if ( index > 11 ) {
      $(this).hide();
   }
});
```

This is another way with jQuery.

Comment: You do not have to manage the index yourself, it is passed in the first argument to the `each()` callback.

Comment: This still has a completely unnecessary increment on `index` (and is very inefficient compared with, say, `slice`).

Comment: Yes, right again... I should stop answering questions at work... Thanks to both of you !

Comment: Unfortunately still not working no idea... I have edited my question to show you my code